# Traveling between Alappuzha and Kollam

Tags: transportation, india, kerala

What are the available means of transport between Alleppy and Kollam? I am interested in going one way only and would prefer taking a backwaters route.

If you do provide an answer, please include how often a vehicle or vessel is going and what the price is approximately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take the DTPC [tourist boat cruise](http://www.dtpcalappuzha.com/intinerary.html) that runs between Alappuzha and Kollam and back. It leaves each town daily from the DTPC jetty at 10:30am and costs Rs300. It is a big boat and doesn't really go in the backwaters but on a pretty wide canal and for some time on a lake. It takes 8 hours and they can be pretty long. I did this just a few weeks ago from Kollam to Alappuzha but did get off halfway at the [Matha Amrithanandamayi ashram](http://www.amritapuri.org/ashram/how2reach) and took the bus from there.

[image: Tourist boat between Alappuzha and Kollam]

From Alappuzha you can take a bus to Karungapally, then another one to the ashram. There you can get on the boat which should get there at around 2pm but you should ask at the DTPC office to confirm this. The boat ride from Kollam to the ashram was Rs100 and the buses Rs30+8. This way you still spend 4 hours on the boat, and I think that is enough. You could also take the boat from Alappuzha to the ashram and then the bus to Karungapally and on to Kollam. I don't know which half of the boat ride is the better one.

Comment: That was my original plan, thanks for backing it up. This ashram seems different so I might as well visit it. So you say I shouldn't have any trouble getting from the ashram to Kollam on land?

Comment: I would also like to know other options such as using canoes, motorboats, houseboats or overland transportation.

Comment: There is a bus from the ashram to the main highway between Alappuzha and Kollam, you can also take a rickshaw. On the highway are tons of buses in both directions. Considering it takes 8 hours on a big bed, any smaller boats will take much longer and would require overnight stays. You could also just take the bus, but that's kind of boring.

Comment: Just to add to your answer, renting a houseboat from Alappuzha to Kollam will set you back between 10,500 to 15,000 rupees either for a drop or return trip. Canoes and motorboats don't do the trip. From mentioned ashram to Kollam, an autorickshaw ride is some 250 rupees and autorickshaw stand is at other side of the backwaters so just cross the bridge or take a 5 rupee boat ride across. Your answer is great because that way you get to break your trip in two shorter ones by staying at the ashram.